# Remove all SQL users from a DB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a database that I am migrating, but when I do the restore all the users of that database are also migrated.

Is there any way to do a restore of the DB only of the data? Without the users/roles

Or any way to remove all users from the DB?

([This users i want to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oc1cQ.jpg))

In total there are 15BBDD with +50 users.

Comment: You can use Dynamic SQL to frame the SQL query and execute it.

Comment: The point of a database backup is that it contains a **full** backup of the database. If you want to remove parts of that database, either remove them after you `RESTORE` it, or make a copy of the database you want to backup first, and remove the things you don't want before you `BACKUP` that copy.

Answer (score 1):

In Management Studio, you can right click on your database, select `Tasks` then `Generate Scripts...`

[image: Generate scripts]

On `Choose Objects` screen choose users you want to remove, or all.

[image: Choose Users]

On `Set scripting options` page, go to `Advanced`, find `Script DROP and CREATE` and choose option to only `Script DROP`
Select option to open in a new query window.
Next, next, finish and you'll have your script to drop all users.

[image: Advanced and choose script DROP]